# Insert pd.dataframe to teradata via bteq

Tags: python, database, pandas, connection, teradata

When I want to insert some data from a pandas dataframe to a teradata table I do the following steps:

1. save the pd.DataFrame as a .csv
2. write a .sql file with the .logon, .import vartext from file, sql insert query and .logoff and save it locally
3. excecute the .sql file with bteq via the python package subprocess
4. wait until the process is finished and then continue with the script.

So the issue here is that it is not really save (e.g. there are laying some files locally around with the databasepassword) and a dependent on the right saving of the csv.

So what i would like to do is the following:

1. create the bteq query internally in the original python process without writing something to a local file (no .csv and no .sql)
2. Execute this query within in the python process

I know that there is already a teradata python package, hoewever it uses odbc and not bteq (there is a possibility to use bteq, but it is the same with executing a .sql file). And odbc is not installed on the server the script is executed.

Comment: Writes into a RDBS table is always faster through file. I guess optimized way would be to write the data into a .csv through `pandas` and then run `bteq` as the next step in the code.

Comment: So that is the normal way to do it? That sounds not really pythonic and unsave....